# Как вставить серверное время с помощью Insert в C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Код такой:

```
MyDataSetTableAdapters.TestTableAdapter CDISEtb = new MyDataSetTableAdapters.TestTableAdapter ();
CDISEtb.Insert(Guid.NewGuid(),"Ололо","Пыщь-пыщь","1",<серверное время>)
```

Вот что следует использовать вместо <серверное время> чтобы сервак вставил свое время? В обычном SQL мы бы использовали:

```
insert into TestTable values (NEWID(), 'Ололо','Пыщь-пыщь','1',GETDATE())
```

Comment: Если MYSQL то `NOW()`

Comment: INSERT INTO TableName() VALUES ('1111', '222', NOW())

Comment: Ребят, я в тэгах указал sql server. Скрипт рабочий, но вопрос касается использования стандартных средств работы с SQL в C#.

Comment: Руслан, а разве это будет не время в среде исполняемого файла, а не время на sql-сервере?

Comment: [SYSDATETIME()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetime-transact-sql)

Comment: Андрей, это функция для SQL скрипта, речь о программе на C#.

Comment: Тогда - никак. Либо делаете сначала Select и получаете системное время сервера

Comment: Как вариант сохранение в хранимой процедуре

Comment: mssql `INSERT INTO TableName() VALUES ('1111', '222', current_timestamp )`

Comment: c# `CDISEtb.Insert(Guid.NewGuid(),"Ололо","Пыщь-пыщь","1", DateTime.Now)`

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов может тогда проще не вставлять это значение из C#, а заполнять его в самой БД, задав этой колонке дефолтное значение как DEFAULT GETDATE()?

Comment: Передавайте дату с таймзоной и не будет никаких проблем, если у вас на обоих машинах (и бекенд и база) настроено время правильно, даже если в разных таймзонах.

Comment: @ApInvent Да, речь о том, чтобы как-то сказать серверу, чтобы он сам проставил дату. Но синтаксис я не знаю, как сделать это в рамках метода Insert. Можно, конечно, банально сделать строку со скриптом уже в виде SQL-языка и отправить на выполнение, но суть вопроса именно в том, можно ли это сделать средствами адаптера таблицы.

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов это можно указать в описании самой таблицы и при вставке данных сервер сам подставит нужное значение. [Тут](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp) можно посмотреть пример. Тогда для этой колонки вообще ничего передавать не надо.

Comment: Адаптер таблицы содержит в себе обычный sql-запрос на вставку. Отредактируйте его, добавив `GETDATE` в саму строку запроса.